# Reuse css elements

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, scss-mixins

I have two scss files. Eg. SCss1 and scss2.

Scss1 has styles for many components and I want to reuse the style in scss2 but without copy and pasting the same code as that would be repetition of code and I want to avoid that. I need an scss2 file because some components have different style properties while many I want to take from scss1 file.

Comment: If you're using it in multiple places, perhaps pull it into it's own file and import it to each of your main files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as DBS suggested
use @import - https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import
or @use - https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use